# How to reverse a global require in Composer?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, zend-studio

A while ago, I added the Laravel framework via a global dependency to my environment through `global require laravel/laravel` in Composer. I'm having an issue though that when I try to edit and add further dependencies to Laravel's composer.json file, my IDE (I use Zend Studio) will not let me add futher dependencies, with an error of

```
Composer.json in dependency package should not be modified.
```

I feel that if I took Laravel out of the `global` dependency, it could solve the issue(?).

I'm not sure how to reverse the `global require` though. I was hoping for something like `global unrequire`, but to no avail. I also was hesitant to do it directly through the global .json file. Is there a command that would remove an item from the dependency?

Comment: It sounds like Zend Studio is being overprotective. Have you tried editing Laravel's composer.json directly (outside of Zend Studio) and re-running composer from the command line to complete the updates? If so, do you encounter any issues?

Comment: That sounds like it might be the issue. I'm running the `require` I need via the command line and everything seems to be running smoothly. I'll see if I can figure out how to change those settings in Zend Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if the global require is actually causing the problem, but to remove the package you have to edit the global `composer.json` and run `composer update`.

The global `composer.json` can be found in the [composer home directory](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-home) which is usually:

Linux: `/home/<user>/.composer`
OSX: `/Users/<user>/.composer`
Windows: `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Composer`

Comment: Thanks for that. I think I'm going to see if I can just add the dependencies via the command line since you mention it probably isn't the issue. Thank you very much.